# Can I consistently grab a specific users data with Spotify API

Tags: javascript, spotify

I can successfully authorize a user and access data using their access token, but I am looking to display the current played song of a specific Spotify user (the user who owns the website I’m designing) to everyone who views the site and I am not sure if this is possible using the Spotify API.

The only constraint is I can only use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The [Player API from Spotify](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#category-player) allows a developer to get the current user's playback, the current playing track, and more. Check out the documentation on which API requests to use to get that information. One can then display the currently playing song on a website for others to see as long as they are authenticated with the correct access tokens. Make sure to choose the [correct authorization flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/) as that will allow you to consistently grab the data without having to reauthorize every time.

Comment: Yes, I know how to use the Spotify API like this, but I’m wondering if there is anyway to use any authorization flow to consistently authorize one specific user on a website for everyone who sees. Let’s say bob is the specific user, when joe checks out the website I want joe to see bobs currently playing song. If Jim, George, and Susie check out the website they should all be able to see Bobs playing song always. Is there a way to do this with the Spotify API because I do not see one at the moment?